# Is there a way to extract a substring from a cell in OpenOffice Calc?

Tags: text-extraction, openoffice-calc

I have tens of thousands of rows of unstructured data in csv format. I need to extract certain product attributes from a long string of text. Given a set of acceptable attributes, if there is a match, I need it to fill in the cell with the match.

Example data:
"[ROOT];Earrings;Brands;Brands>JeweleryExchange;Earrings>Gender;Earrings>Gemstone;Earrings>Metal;Earrings>Occasion;Earrings>Style;Earrings>Gender>Women's;Earrings>Gemstone>Zircon;Earrings>Metal>White Gold;Earrings>Occasion>Just to say: I Love You;Earrings>Style>Drop/Dangle;Earrings>Style>Fashion;Not Visible;Gifts;Gifts>Price>$500 - $1000;Gifts>Shop>Earrings;Gifts>Occasion;Gifts>Occasion>Christmas;Gifts>Occasion>Just to say: I Love You;Gifts>For>Her"

Look up table of values:
Zircon, Diamond, Pearl, Ruby

Output:
Zircon

I tried using the VLOOKUP() function, but it needs to match an entire cell and works better for translating acronyms. Haven't really found a built in function that accomplishes what I need. The data is totally unstructured, and changes from row to row with no consistency even within variations of the same product. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?? Or how to write an OpenOffice Calc function to accomplish this? Also open to other better methods of doing this if anyone has any experience or ideas in how to approach this...

Comment: Some questions: (1) What do you mean exactly by "fill in the cell with the match" - should the complete string starting from `[ROOT]` till `Gifts>For>Her` be returned? (2) How are the entries separated - by line breaks? (3) Which output format is required?

Comment: @tohuwawohu above is the actual data... that is one line. Output is in csv format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I figured out how to do this on my own... I created many different columns, each with a keyword I was looking to extract as a header.
[Spreadsheet solution for structured data extraction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6LRO.png)
Then I used this formula to extract the keywords into the correct row beneath the column header. =IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(CF$1,$D769)),"",CF$1)    The Search function returns a number value for the position of a search string otherwise it produces an error. I use the iserror function to determine if there is an error condition, and the if statement in such a way that if there is an error, it leaves the cell blank, else it takes the value of the header. Had over 100 columns of specific information to extract, into one final column where I join all the previous cells in the row together for the final list. Worked like a charm. Recommend this approach to anyone who has to do a similar task.